# Skip image during tensorflow input pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow input pipeline that reads in two png files (example, label) from disk. I want to tell tensorflow to skip an example/label pair based on a value in the label. Anyone know how to do this?

Here is a simplified example of the input pipeline and with a comment where I want to do the filtering:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob2 as glob

def preprocess_images(impath, labpath):
     image = tf.io.read_file(impath)
     label = tf.io.read_file(labpath)
     image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
     label = tf.image.decode_png(label, channels=1)
     if tf.reduce_sum(label) == 0:
          #skip the image and move on to the next, don't include this in the batch
     else:
          return (image, label)

im_files = glob.glob(impath + '*.png')
lab_files = glob.glob(labpath + '*.png')

files = (im_files, lab_files)
path = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
pair = path.map(preprocess_images)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(pair)
ds = ds.batch(64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be to use [filter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) method on your `tf.data.Dataset` object.

Here I am going to load the label only and filter out the entries with a sum of 0:

```py
def load_label_only(impath, labpath):
    label = tf.io.read_file(labpath)
    label = tf.image.decode_png(label, channels=1)
    return impath, label


# Create the dataset as in your example:

im_files = glob.glob(impath + '*.png')
lab_files = glob.glob(labpath + '*.png')

files = (im_files, lab_files)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
ds = ds.map(load_label_only)

# Here, I am going to keep only non-zero labels:
filtered_ds = ds.filter(lambda image_path, label_map: tf.reduce_sum(label_map) != 0)

# Load the rest of the images...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could I ask you one more question? Lets say I want to instead of eliminate all labels that sum to zero, I want to keep 10 of them per batch? Any idea how you would do that?